# Warn only when *calling* a deprecated method

Tags: c++, c++11, deprecation-warning

I want to mark a pure virtual method in a base class `deprecated`, and get a compiler warning when someone tries to call the method (or its overrides) somewhere, but *not*, like it currently is, for every declaration of an override—because the method is pure virtual in the base class, all child classes *must* implement it to be instantiable, but that means every one of those overrides produces a (or multiple) compiler warning(s), which kinda spams the output.
So I'd like to throw the warning only when the method (or one of the overrides) is being *called*.

Is that possible somehow without jumping through hoops*?

PS: I mark the base method as deprecated using the following macro:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated)
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
    #define DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
#else
    #pragma message("WARNING: DEPRECATED macro not implemented for this compiler")
    #define DEPRECATED
#endif
```

…and I'm currently compiling in VS2015.
The compiler warnings are output both if I only mark the base method deprecated and if I use the macro on both the base method and the overrides.

*) *like putting a message(...) or static assert into every overrides' function definition and inlining them, or something like that... I don't think that would be worth it.*

Comment: Clang and GCC only complain when the function is called, not declared or overridden. [Here it is on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/NzCybD). I think it's a QoI issue.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ah, good to know, thanks for checking, I should've thought of that. I hope it's not something I simply have to live with for the MSVC solution… =/

Comment: Create an intermediary type that disables the warning, overrides the method, then reenables the warning?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Cool idea!

Comment: What happens if you declare the override methods as also deprecated?

Comment: I've used the form in MSVC 2015: `#define DEPRECATED(msg) __declspec(deprecated("deprecated. " msg))`, and it only seems to report the deprecated messages for call locations, not the declaration.

Comment: @GemTaylor Like I wrote: "The compiler warnings are output both if I only mark the base method deprecated and if I use the macro on both the base method and the overrides."

Comment: OK fair enough. I didn't spot that and thought I'd ask, as that would be an obvious fix: In my eyes one deprecated method should be allowed to call/derive another without raising a further warning, but perhaps only if they are both tagged with the same deprecation. Now we get into the land of a hierarchy of deprecation tags - where will it end? [imagine the old API (deprecated) calls the 'new' API; later, the new API is also replaced...